# RegEx Capture First String between Two Numbers

Tags: regex, string, numbers, between, digits

Trying to extract 1st match string between numbers:
For example:

testsfa13.4**extractthis**8488.9090testssffwwww

ajfafs-sss133.6**extractthis**887878.222testtest522252.9thismore

So far I have the following:

```
[\d](.*?)[\d]
```

However, the match includes the numbers at the end of capture group? Any suggestions appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract the first match, you could start with an anchor `^` matching any char except a digit `\D*` and then match a digit with an optional decimal part.

```
^\D*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(\D+)\d
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\D*` Match 0+ times any char except a digit
- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat a `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
- `(\D+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char except a digit
- `\d` Match a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDtuzP/1)

To prevent crossing newline boundaries:

```
^[^\d\n\r]*\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*([^\d\n\r]+)\d
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ddbh2x/1)

Answer (score 1):

try `\d([A-Za-z]+)\d` and get first value from returned object

https://regex101.com/r/v61exp/1